# #VBA #Excel - Stretched and shifted pictures

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project using VBA with Excel. By clicking a button, we generate an array. One line refers to one product. The information is stored in each column (column A = reference, column B = name...). The generation is made with some code using VBA.
The problem concerns the pictures. I managed the shape of the pictures, so they are placed in the cell, with a certain height, width, placement...

When I generate the array from my computer, there's no problem, the pictures are placed perfectly.
When the array is generated from another computer, the pictures look stretched and shifted. That's it from the 12th line to the end (but the first 11 lines are okay). I don't understand why it starts from the 12th line because the code is exactly the same for every line of the array. And above all, I don't understand why the array isn't well generated on every computer.

The Excel version is the same and the pictures options too.
Have you heard about something like that?
Thanks a lot for your comments!

---

Here's the code:

```vb
Function SetImageViewer(Ref As String, Cell As Range) As String
    Dim cmt As Comment
    Dim sPicName As String
    Dim ImageCell As Range
    Dim OrderFormWS As Worksheet
    
    sPicName = GetParameter("PicturesPath") & "\" & Ref & ".jpg"
    Set ImageCell = Cell.MergeArea
    Set OrderFormWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OrderForm")

    sPicFile = Dir(sPicName)
    If sPicFile <> vbNullString Then
        
        Set Pic = OrderFormWS.Shapes.AddPicture(sPicName, linktofile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=0, Height:=0)
        With Pic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Left = ImageCell.Left + 5
            .Top = ImageCell.Top + 5
            .Width = 40
            .Height = 40
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        
        Set cmt = Cell.Comment
        If cmt Is Nothing Then Set cmt = Cell.AddComment()
        cmt.Text " "
        cmt.Shape.Fill.UserPicture sPicName
        cmt.Shape.Height = 300
        cmt.Shape.Width = 300
        SetImageViewer = ChrW(&H25BA)
    Else
        Set cmt = Cell.Comment
        If Not cmt Is Nothing Then cmt.Delete
        SetImageViewer = "No picture"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share the code with us and an example of an image that gets stretched?

Comment: You have to edit your post above and add it there.

Comment: I edited my post, thanks for the advice !

Comment: I have looked at it but I don't see anything obvious in the code.

Comment: I changed Pic.Placement value for ".Placement = xlMove" : the pictures are not stretched any more, but still shifted. Any idea ?